# Returning a string value before given character in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to extrapolate year and month from a single string wich in the format mm/yyyy. I'm looking for a function where I can give in input the string, and the character I want for the string to stop being copied. I'd like it to return just the "mm" or "yyyy" part.

Is there any known function that does what I'm trying to do? Or should I just make it myself?

Comment: [`$var = explode('/', 'mm/yyyy')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), then `$var[0]` for `mm` and `$var[1]` for `yyyy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list($month, $year) = explode("/", "mm/yyyy");
echo $month; // would display the month
echo $year; // would display the year
```

[`List()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) is used to assign variables as if they were an array, and [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) splits your string into an array using the forward slash as a deliemeter.

[**DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/rQY7g)

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y', '10/2014');
$date->format('Y'); //returns 2014
$date->format('m'); //returns 10
```

$date is now a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php) object and you can work with it like any other DateTime object.

Alternative: [date_parse_from_format](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-parse-from-format.php)

Comment: Flip your year and month around, but I upped this answer because this is more semantically correct and should be safer to use.